# Hibernate + MySQL. Ways to optimize selecting and loading data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, query-optimization

I'd like to test how selecting and loading data in java application using `hibernate` and `mysql` can be optimized.

I divided results I found into 2 groups

**MySQL**

- indexes - for sure
- stored procedures - is there a difference if select is done in stored procedure?
- views - is there a difference if select definition is kept in view?
- query cache - does it work only if we do the same select second time?

**Hibernate**

- hibernate cache - is this similar to query cache? how it can be configured?
- lazy loading - can it help?

Are there any other ways? I use simple queries with several joins and aggregation functions. 
I need to demonstate time changes between "before" and "after" optimization.

For more information I tried to read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html), but language is to complicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Batch fetching is important when you read e.g. a collection. In that case Hibernate can get many rows of the collection in one SQL request, so that it would be faster.
2. Hibernate caching is very good solution (read about EHCache for instance) it can store retrieved data on memory and if nothing changes on his side it can retrieve it without even asking SQL engine what's going on there.
3. Lazy loading is a must for One to Many associations (you can kill your solution without this). But fortunately it is set by default in Hibernate for such associations.

You can also read about optimistic lock, which is faster than pessimistic lock in many cases.

Last but not least you should use proper transaction strategy, so that you shouldn't create new transactions when it is not necessary.